# Dark Children's book involving searching for keys

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember the title of a children's picture book I last read years ago.
The illustrations were rather dark and elaborate/intricate.
The plot followed a man, I think as he searched for keys through a large city. I remember it being 7 keys in Paris, but that may not be correct.

I feel like this may not be enough to identify the book, but it's all I remember. I hope this sounds familiar to someone.

Comment: https://www.kidsreads.com/reviews/the-eureka-key-secrets-of-the-seven

Comment: When you say `last read years ago` what do you mean? Like 5, 10, 50? Also, when might have been the _first_ time you read it?

Comment: What language was it in?